# How do trigger reloadRowsAtIndexPaths from a cell?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add up and down votes on my UITableCells

Here is what I mean:

[image]

Whenever I click on up and down button it should update the cell immediately

Here is how I'm populating the table:

Code block in my UITableView

```
...
...

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  return getCellForIndexPath(indexPath)
}

func getCellForIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> TableCell {
  let cell = tblView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableCell") as! TableCell
  if generalPosts.count != 0 {
    let post = generalPosts[indexPath.row]
    cell.post.text = post.value["post"] as? String
    let test = post.value["time"] as? NSNumber
    let time = Double(test!)
    cell.time.text = getTimeAgo(time)
    cell.votes.text = String(Int((post.value["votes"] as? NSNumber)!))
    cell.snapShot = post
  }
  return cell
}
...
...
```

Here is my UITableCell

```
import UIKit

class TableCell: UITableViewCell {
  @IBOutlet var userImage: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet var post: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet var time: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet var votes: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet var thumbsUp: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet var thumbsDown: UIButton!

  var snapShot: FDataSnapshot? = nil
  var newValue: Int = 0

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    newValue = Int(snapShot?.value["votes"] as! NSNumber)
    thumbsUp.addTarget(self, action: "upOne:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    thumbsDown.addTarget(self, action: "downOne:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
  }

  @IBAction func upOne(sender: UIButton) {
    let ref = snapShot!.ref
    newValue = newValue + 1
    ref.updateChildValues(["votes": newValue])
  }

  @IBAction func downOne(sender: UIButton) {
    let ref = snapShot!.ref
    newValue = newValue - 1
    ref.updateChildValues(["votes": newValue])
  }
}
```

The Up and Down buttons they work somewhat, but I have to refresh the page in order to get the right number of votes to show up. How can I make the cell refresh as soon as one of the up or down buttons are clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table shouldnt need to reload the cell to update that, the cell can take care of that itself surely

in cellForRowAtIndexPath, pass the whole `post` object instead of just the value at "votes"

then inside your one up and down functions just put

```
self.votes.text = String(Int((post.value["votes"] as? NSNumber)!))
```

provided `ref.updateChildValues(["votes": newValue])` updated the post object appropriately already

Answer (score 1):

how about just update the label of the cell after you set the new value like

```
votes.text = "\(newValue)"
```